# Repeated section titles clipping / overflowing through page

Tags: header-footer, margins, classicthesis, sections-paragraphs

So I am currently writing a report in Latex, I chose to use the "classicthesis" template in the Overleaf editor.

The problem I have is
that the repeated section titles (i.e. if I begin a section and the paragraph continues on a new page it prints the section title in the header.). Now I have fairly long titles and the titles that are in the header are clipping through the page margins as seen in the image attached image underneath.

I figure it has something to do with the titlesec or KOMA package; however, I can't find any options in the preabmble file (attached as pastebin), to configure these repeated heading titles.

The pastebin of the preamble/config:
https://pastebin.com/Njjh7bST

Thanks in advance.

[image: overflowing heading]

Comment: Why must you have such long title? In any case, look [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-runheadtoobig) for ways to include an abbreviation of the titles.

Comment: That did the trick!  all this time I have been searching with the wrong keywords! Thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer, the titles I used directly reflect the research questions for the research in my internship report.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\section[Short Title]{Long Title}`.  The "Long Title" will appear as the section head, but the "Short Title" will be used in the running header and the table of contents.

If that's not sufficient, you can try one of the other options at https://texfaq.org/FAQ-runheadtoobig that @Jeffrey J Weimer linked to.